# why i am geeting Index Out Of Bounds Exception error

Tags: java

Here,I'm trying to print next consonant letter, suppose if i give input as java outpt should look as kava. As j and v are consonant therefore it should print next letter if it is a consonant

Enter any string = java
bjcException in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Consonants.main(Consonants.java:30)

```
    String consonants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ".toLowerCase();

    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter any string = ");
    String inputString = bf.readLine().toLowerCase();

    for(int i=0; i < inputString.length(); i++){
        inputChar = inputString.charAt(i);
        //int asciiInput = (int) inputChar; 
        String str1 = inputString.charAt(i) + "";
        int asciiInput = (int) str1.charAt(i);

        for(int j = 0; j < consonants.length(); j++){
         stringChar = consonants.charAt(j);
         System.out.print(stringChar);
         //int asciiConsonants = (int) stringChar;
         String str2 = consonants.charAt(j) + "";
         int asciiConsonants = (int) str2.charAt(j);

         if( !str1.equals(str2) ){
             nextChar = (char) asciiInput;
             System.out.print(nextChar);
         } else if ( str1.equals(str2) ) {
             nextChar = (char) (asciiConsonants + 1);
             System.out.print(nextChar);     
         }

        }
    }
```

Comment: int asciiConsonants = (int) str2.charAt(j); //str2 is only 2 chars long. 'j' goes up to 21.

Comment: @ABuckau it's 1 char.

Answer (score 1):

`str2` will have only 1 character becaue `consonants.charAt(j)` will get 1 character and, `""` contains 0 characters.

On the other hand, `consonants` contains more than 1 character.
Therefore, `j` will become `1` and `str2.charAt(j);` will emit the error.

You may want `(int) str1.charAt(0)` and `(int) str2.charAt(0)` instead of `(int) str1.charAt(i)` and `(int) str2.charAt(j)`.

Comment: same problem with i too

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error is because `str1` and `str2` are single-character strings, so `charAt()` will be out of bounds unless `i` and `j` are 0.

Also, if you'll forgive me, I've made some enhancements to your code:

```
String vowels = "aeiou";
String inputString = bf.readLine().toLowerCase();
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    char c = inputString.charAt(i);
    boolean isVowel = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < vowels.length(); j++) {
        if (vowels.charAt(j) == c) {
            isVowel = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(isVowel ? c : (char)(c + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what's causing your exception:

```
    String str1 = inputString.charAt(i) + "";
    int asciiInput = (int) str1.charAt(i);
```

str1 only has one character, on the second iteration you are asking for the second non-existent character. you'll only work when the index is 0.